# How to build all projects in the solution in specific configuration (as if you choose "Rebuild Solution")

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have to build all projects in solution in specific configuration (debug, release) just the same way Visual Studio does when you choose "Rebuild Solution".

How can I do that with msbuild?

I expect that binaries should appear just in project\bin\debug|release folders as usual.

I tried several msbuild configuration files I found in Internet but in vain.

Please help me to automate such a task and thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MSBuild.exe sample.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU
MSBuild.exe sample.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU
MSBuild.exe sample.sln /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergio, that works, though I should use Platform="Any CPU". There said "access is denied to unregister my dll". I guess msbuild should be run as administator as well

Comment: Yeah, that's super bizarre: when you run `msbuild` against a .csproj file it wants `AnyCPU`, and when you run it against an .sln file it wants `"Any CPU"`...